# LINQ Filtering Select Ouput with IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have following methods:

Controller:

```
...
var appmap = Services.GetReqAppMapList(value);
var applist = Services.GetApplicationList(docid, appid, reqid, appmap);
...
```

Model:

```
public static IEnumerable<AppMap> GetReqAppMapList(int aiRequestTypeId)
{
    try
    {
        var appmap = new List<AppMap>();
        using (var eties = new eRequestsEntities())
        {
            appmap = (from ram in eties.ReqAppMaps 
                      where ram.IsActive == 1
                      select new AppMap
                      {
                          RequestTypeId = ram.RequestTypeId
                      }).ToList();
            return appmap;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }           
}

public static IEnumerable<TicketApplication> GetApplicationList(int aiDocumentTypeId, int aiApplicationTypeId, int aiRequestTypeId, IEnumerable<AppMap> appmap)
{
    try
    {
        var applicationlist = new List<TicketApplication>();                    
        using (var applicationentity = new eRequestsEntities())
        {                 
            applicationlist = (from app in applicationentity.Applications
                               where 1==1   
                                <<<Some Conditions Here???>>>
== && appmap.Contains(app.ApplicationTypeId) ==
                                && app.IsActive == 1
                               select new TicketApplication
                               {
                                   ApplicationId = app.ApplicationId,
                                   Description = app.Description,
                                   DeliveryGroupId = app.DeliveryGroupId,
                                   ApplicationTypeId = app.ApplicationTypeId,
                                   DeliveryTypeId = app.DeliveryTypeId,
                                   DocumentTypeId = app.DocumentTypeId,
                                   SupportGroupId = app.SupportGroupId
                               }).OrderBy(a => a.Description).ToList();

            return applicationlist;
}
```

And I was thinking how can filter query result of GetApplicationList using the result from GetReqAppMapList

I'm kinda stuck with the fact that I must convert/cast something to the correct type because every time I do a result.Contains (appmap.Contains to be exact), I always get the following error

> Error 4   Instance argument: cannot convert from 
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Test.Models.AppMap>'` to 
>   `'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int?>'`

Comment: How/where do you use GetReqAppMapList? You will need to provide more code...

Comment: Can you show an example of how and where you were calling `appmap.Contains`

Comment: Since the only place where you mention ParallelQuery is in that error message it is kinda hard knowing what it is that you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should directly join the two tables in one query.

```
using (var applicationentity = new eRequestsEntities())
{                 
    applicationlist = (from app in applicationentity.Applications
                       join ram in applicationentity.ReqAppMaps on app.ApplicationTypeId equals ram.RequestTypeId
                        where ram.IsActive == 1 && app.IsActive == 1
                       select new TicketApplication
                       {
                           ApplicationId = app.ApplicationId,
                           Description = app.Description,
                           DeliveryGroupId = app.DeliveryGroupId,
                           ApplicationTypeId = app.ApplicationTypeId,
                           DeliveryTypeId = app.DeliveryTypeId,
                           DocumentTypeId = app.DocumentTypeId,
                           SupportGroupId = app.SupportGroupId
                       }).OrderBy(a => a.Description).ToList();
```

You can delete the other method if it is not needed anymore. No point hanging onto code which is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no other way to do this (as far as I know), so I have to refactor the code, I hope still that there would be a straight forward conversion and matching method in the future (too lazy). Anyway, please see below for my solution. Hope this helps someone with the same problem in the future. I'm not sure about the performance, but this should work for now.

Controller:

```
...
var appmap = Services.GetReqAppMapList(value);
var applist = Services.GetApplicationList(docid, appid, reqid, appmap);
...
```

Model:

```
<Removed GetReqAppMapList>--bad idea

public static IEnumerable<TicketApplication> GetApplicationList(int aiDocumentTypeId, int aiApplicationTypeId, int aiRequestTypeId)
{
    try
    {
       //This is the magic potion...
       List<int?> appmap = new List<int?>();
       var applist = (from ram in applicationentity.ReqAppMaps
                      where ram.RequestTypeId == aiRequestTypeId
                       && ram.IsActive == 1
                      select new AppMap
                      {
                         ApplicationTypeId = ram.ApplicationTypeId
                      }).ToList();

      foreach (var item in applist)
      {
         appmap.Add(item.ApplicationTypeId);
      }
      //magic potion end

      var applicationlist = new List<TicketApplication>();                    
      using (var applicationentity = new eRequestsEntities())
      {                 
         applicationlist = (from app in applicationentity.Applications
                            where 1==1
                        ===>>>&& appmap.Contains(app.ApplicationTypeId)<<<===
                             && app.IsActive == 1
                               select new TicketApplication
                               {
                                   ApplicationId = app.ApplicationId,
                                   Description = app.Description,
                                   DeliveryGroupId = app.DeliveryGroupId,
                                   ApplicationTypeId =app.ApplicationTypeId,
                                   DeliveryTypeId = app.DeliveryTypeId,
                                   DocumentTypeId = app.DocumentTypeId,
                                   SupportGroupId = app.SupportGroupId
                               }).OrderBy(a => a.Description).ToList();

            return applicationlist;
}
```

A side-note, C# is a strongly-typed language, just make sure your data types matches during evaluation, as **int?** vs **int** etc..,  will never compile. A small dose of LINQ is enough to send some newbies circling around for hours. One of my ID-10T programming experience but just enough to remind me that my feet's still flat on the ground.